# Set a class property to a class in VBA?

Tags: vba, class, vb6

Not sure how to express this in writing but I'll try, please let me know if you want more explanations?

I'm trying to set a class property - which is defined as a custom class object type - to a defined variable with the same type of class. The problem is I'm getting this error:

`Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

So, let's say we have these two classes:

**MT940Message**

```
Public BasicHeaderInput As String
Public ApplicationHeaderInput As String
Public Trailer As String
Public Text As MT940TextObject
```

**MT940TextObject**

```
Public TransactionReferenceNumber As String
Public RelatedReference As String
Public AccountIdentification As String
Public StatementNumber As String
Public OpeningBalance As String
Public StatementLine As String
Public InformationToAccountOwner As String
Public ClosingBalance As String
Public ClosingAvailableBalance As String
Public ForwardAvailableBalance As String
Public InformationToAccountOwner2 As String
```

And then I'm doing something like

```
Dim message As MT940Message
Set message = New MT940Message

Dim newTextObject As MT940TextObject
Set newTextObject = New MT940TextObject


newTextObject.TransactionReferenceNumber = "ref123"
newTextObject.RelatedReference = "rel123"
newTextObject.AccountIdentification "456677"

message.ApplicationHeaderInput = "abc"
message.BasicHeaderInput = "def"
message.Trailer = "ghi"
message.Text = newTextObject ' this causes Run-time error '91'
```

When I debug `message.Text` is equal to `Nothing`.

Comment: use `Set` keyword with objects: `Set message.Text = newTextObject `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `.Text` property is an object reference, try using `Set` such as:

`Set message.Text = newTextObject`.